# Array is giving wrong output?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, integer

Input:

```
1
7
4 2 4 1 4 3 4
```

Output:

```
[I@59e84876
4
```

The expected output for the array should be [4 2 4 1 4 3 4] but why is it giving some random string as output but the Hashset is giving perfect output.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n=s.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            int no=s.nextInt();

            HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<>();
            int[] arr = new int[no];

            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                int x=s.nextInt();
                arr[j]=x;
                h.add(x);
            }
        }

           System.out.println(arr);
           System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is invalid and cannot compile, *h* and *arr* defined *inside* the *for* but you print them *outside* the *for*

Comment: When moving the 2 print inside the loop the result is not the one you give, "4" is replaced by "[1, 2, 3, 4]".

Comment: "it giving some random string" no, that indicates it is an array ([) of *int* (I) and its address

Comment: @SadmanSakib , thankyou it is working but why converting into string?

Comment: @bruno , thankyou i understood

Comment: For printing arrays just use `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's an error in your code. You should initialize the instance of HashSet and int[] array out of the for loop scope to access it beyond that loop's scope.

If you get that right then the answer to your question is, when you print an array Object.toString() method is called. Which returns a [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) value as you mentioned "random string" in your question. On the other hand, HashSet overrides the toString() method and returns a string representation.

As mentioned in the documentation -

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

So, to print a string representation of the integer array in your code, you could use the Arrays class from util package. The code would be like this-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

If you had a multidimensional array then you could use the following-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define `arr` and `h` before/outside the for loop.
Secondly, if you want your array output to look like this - [4 2 4 1 4 3 4], there are 2 ways:
1. Use ArrayList instead of primitive int array, i.e. 
`List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();` and add the entries.
2. Don't print the array `arr` directly with `println()`, instead use a loop:

```
System.out.print("[");
for (int i: arr)
  if (i!=arr[arr.length-1])
    System.out.print(i + ",");
  else 
    System.out.print(i + "]");
```

Comment: You don't need to implement it. It's already in the JDK. Just use `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`.